# Scroll UIImage texture coordinates

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an `UIImageView` with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` attached. When the user pans across the view, I want to scroll it's texture coordinates thus showing rotation process.

Do I have any access to `UIImage` texture coordinates, and is it possible to change them in runtime?